# This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities

I get the error message in the Title, which is not very helpful.
Situation:

```
Reduce[ForAll[{x,y,z},Implies[x<=y&&y<=z, x<=z]]]
```

evaluates to True, but

```
Reduce[ForAll[{x,y,z,w},Implies[ x>=0&&y>=0&&z>=0&&w>=0&&x+y<= z+w,xyw>=wwz]]]
```

gives "This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce". Any explanation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put spaces or * between your variables `xyz` and `wwz` to give:

```
Reduce[ForAll[{x, y, z, w}, 
  Implies[x >= 0 && y >= 0 && z >= 0 && w >= 0 && x + y <= z + w, 
   x*y*w >= w*w*z]]]
(* result False *)
```

Comment: Duh... okay if I may be permitted to make the question slightly more interesting, I get the same problem with `Reduce[ForAll[{x010,x011,x100,x101,x111},Implies[ x001+x101 <=x010+x110&&x010+x110<=x100+x101 && x010>=0&&x011>=0&&x100>=0&&x101>=0&&x111>=0,x010^2 x100>=0]]]`

Comment: For that problem you missed some variables in your `ForAll`. Try `Reduce[ForAll[{x000, x001, x010, x011, x100, x101, x110, x111}, 
  Implies[x001 + x101 <= x010 + x110 && x010 + x110 <= x100 + x101 && 
    x010 >= 0 && x011 >= 0 && x100 >= 0 && x101 >= 0 && x111 >= 0, 
   x010^2 x100 >= 0]]]` I get result `True`

Comment: Thanks, I guess in light of your answer my question was really just about the fact that "This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce" is not very enlightening, maybe this Q&A will help future searchers learn that it is just a generic message used for very basic errors.

Comment: @Bjørn, I would interpret it more as `Reduce[]` not knowing what to do when you suddenly added the new variables `xyw` and `wwz` which it was not previously told about. ;)

Comment: You could create a `check` function to spot any mistakes `check[expr_, vars_] := 
 Block[{b = Complement[Variables[Level[expr, {-1}]], variables]}, 
  If[b != {}, 
   Print["There are bad variables in your expression: " <> 
     ToString[b]]]]`